# Make CSS transformations not relative to element

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

```js
const 
  doc = document,
  qS = `querySelector`,
  qSA = `querySelectorAll`,
  root = doc[ qS ]( `html` ),
  cubeContainer = doc[ qS ]( `.cube-container` ),
  cubeWrap = doc[ qS ]( `.cube-wrap` ),
  cube = doc[ qS ]( `.cube` ),
  aside = doc[ qS ]( `aside` );

function clicked( event ) {
  const element = event.target;

  if( element.classList == `x-rotate` ) {
    cubeContainer.style.transform += 
      `rotateY( 45deg )`;
  }
  if( element.classList == `y-rotate` ) {
    cubeWrap.style.transform += 
      `rotateX( -45deg )`;
  }
  if( element.classList == `z-rotate` ) {
    cube.style.transform += 
      `rotateZ( 45deg )`;
  }
}

aside.addEventListener( `click`, clicked );
```

```css
body, section, aside, div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
::selection {
  background-color: var( --dim );
}
:root {
  --length: 10rem;
  --dim: rgba( 0,0,0,0.125 );
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
body {
  perspective: 15rem;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.scene-wrap {
  transform: translateZ( -7.5rem );
}
.scene {
  transform: scale( 1 );
}
.cube-container, .cube-container div {
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
.cube-container, .cube-container div {
  width: var( --length );
  height: var( --length );
  position: absolute;
}
.cube > div > div {
  transform: translateZ( 5rem );
}
.cube > div > div:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translateZ( 5rem );
}
.cube > div > div > div {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 1rem inset;
  background-color: var( --dim );
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: transform, box-shadow, background-color;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-out;
}
.cube > div > div > div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 1rem #099 inset;
  background-color: rgba( 0,220,220,0.5 );
}
.cube > div > div > div:active {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 2rem #033 inset;
}
.cube .left-right {
  transform: rotateY( 90deg );
}
.cube .top-bottom {
  transform: rotateX( 90deg );
}
.cube .transform {
  transform: translateZ( 5rem ) scale( 0.75 );
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 3rem inset;
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.75 );
}
.cube .transform:hover {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 4rem #099 inset;
}
aside {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform: scale( 0.65 );
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0rem;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  max-width: 10rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: rgba( 220,220,220,0.5 );
  backdrop-filter: blur( 1rem );
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 1rem );
}
aside svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: scale( 0.65 );
  cursor: pointer;
}
aside svg:hover, aside svg:active {
  fill: #0dd;
}
aside svg:active {
  filter: brightness( 75% );
}
aside svg.y-rotate {
  transform: scale( 0.65 ) rotateZ( 90deg ) scaleY( -1 );
}
```

```html
<!-- \\\ \\ \\ SCENE CONTAINER // // /// -->
<section class='scene-container'>
  <!-- \\ \\\ \\\ SCENE WRAP /// /// // -->
  <section class='scene-wrap'>
    <!-- \\\ \\\ \\\ SCENE /// /// /// -->
    <section class='scene'>
      <!-- \ \ \ CUBE CONTAINER / / / -->
      <div class='cube-container'>
        <!-- \ \ \ CUBE WRAP / / / -->
        <div class='cube-wrap'>
          <!-- \ \ \ CUBE / / / -->
          <div class='cube'>
            <!-- \ front-back / -->
            <div class='front-back'>
              <!-- \ front-wrap / -->
              <div class='front-wrap'>
                <!-- \ front-face / -->
                <div class='front face'>
                </div>
                <!-- / front-face \ -->
              </div>
              <!-- / front-wrap \ -->
              <!-- \ back-wrap / -->
              <div class='back-wrap'>
                <!-- \ back-face / -->
                <div class='back face'>
                </div>
                <!-- / back-face \ -->
              </div>   
              <!-- / back-wrap \ -->
            </div>
            <!-- / front-back \ -->
            <!-- \ left-right / -->
            <div class='left-right'>
              <!-- \ left-wrap / -->
              <div class='left-wrap'>
                <!-- \ left-face / -->
                <div class='left face'>
                </div>
                <!-- / left-face \ -->
              </div>
              <!-- / left-wrap \ -->
              <!-- \ right-wrap / -->
              <div class='right-wrap'>
                <!-- \ right-face / -->
                <div class='right face'>
                </div>
                <!-- / right-face \ -->
              </div>        
              <!-- / right-wrap \ -->
            </div>   
            <!-- / left-right \ -->
            <!-- \ top-bottom / -->
            <div class='top-bottom'>
              <!-- \ top-wrap / -->
              <div class='top-wrap'>
                <!-- \ top-wrap / -->
                <div class='top face'>
                </div>
                <!-- / top-wrap \ -->
              </div>
              <!-- / top-wrap \ -->
              <!-- \ bottom-wrap / -->
              <div class='bottom-wrap'>
                <!-- \ bottom-face / -->
                <div class='bottom face'>
                </div>
                <!-- / bottom-face \ -->
              </div>         
              <!-- / bottom-wrap \ -->
            </div> 
            <!-- / top-bottom \ -->
          </div>
          <!-- / / / CUBE \ \ \ -->
        </div>
        <!-- / / / CUBE WRAP \ \ \ -->
      </div>
      <!-- / / / CUBE CONTAINER \ \ \ -->
    </section>
    <!-- /// /// /// SCENE \\\ \\\ \\\ -->
  </section>
  <!-- // /// /// SCENE WRAP \\\ \\\ \\ -->
</section>
<!-- /// // // SCENE CONTAINER \\ \\ \\\ -->

<!-- \\\ \\\ \\\ ASIDE /// /// /// -->
<aside>
  <!-- \\\ \\\ \\\ X-ROTATE /// /// /// -->
  <svg class='x-rotate'>
    <path 
      class='x-rotate'
      d=
        '
          M 42,75
          C 50,70,58,63,65,59
          C 58,53,50,48,42,43
          V 53
          C -25,44,56,28,82,41
          C 91,46,78,50,72,51
          V 62
          C 114,51,100,28,59,26
          C 18,24,-14,41,10,56
          C 21,62,30,62,42,64
          Z
        '
    />
  </svg>
  <!-- /// /// /// X-ROTATE \\\ \\\ \\\ -->
  <!-- \\\ \\\ \\\ Y-ROTATE /// /// /// -->
  <svg class='y-rotate'>
    <path 
      class='y-rotate'
      d=
        '
          M 42,75
          C 50,70,58,63,65,59
          C 58,53,50,48,42,43
          V 53
          C -25,44,56,28,82,41
          C 91,46,78,50,72,51
          V 62
          C 114,51,100,28,59,26
          C 18,24,-14,41,10,56
          C 21,62,30,62,42,64
          Z
        '
    />
  </svg>
  <!-- /// /// /// Y-ROTATE \\\ \\\ \\\ -->
  <!-- \\\ \\\ \\\ Z-ROTATE /// /// /// -->
  <svg class='z-rotate'>
    <path 
      class='z-rotate'
      d=
        '
          M 94,65
          L 83,61
          C 79,70,73,77,63,80
          C 44,87,23,77,17,59
          C 7,24,48,0,76,26
          L 64,32 L 96,50 L 97,15 L 86,20
          C 62,-4,32,4,17,18
          C -8,44,7,77,27,87
          C 52,100,85,90,94,65
          Z
        '
    />
  </svg>
  <!-- /// /// /// Z-ROTATE \\\ \\\ \\\ -->
</aside>
<!-- /// /// /// ASIDE \\\ \\\ \\\ -->
```

The controls on the left side of the snippet rotate the cube in the respective direction when clicked. The problem I'm having is all rotations are relative to the cube itself, but I want to rotate relative to the document "view".

Example: clicking on the topmost control first rotates the cube right, then immediately after clicking on the middle control rotates the cube down from its top. However this second rotation rotates the cube down relative to it's first rotation. What I want is to rotate the cube down as if it's first rotation wasn't taken into consideration.

Every rotation should take whatever position the cube is in and rotate in the clicked direction "globally" not relative to the cube.

### How can I "freeze transforms" or "reset" rotations after each button click so the subsequent rotations aren't relative to the previous ones?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, a little bit better, snaps a bit when you change rotations though, not sure if that's what you were looking for:

```js
const 
  doc = document,
  qS = `querySelector`,
  qSA = `querySelectorAll`,
  root = doc[ qS ]( `html` ),
  cubeContainer = doc[ qS ]( `.cube-container` ),
  cubeWrap = doc[ qS ]( `.cube-wrap` ),
  cube = doc[ qS ]( `.cube` ),
  aside = doc[ qS ]( `aside` );

let rotplane=1,
    roty=0,
    rotx=0,
    rotz=0;

function clearTransform(){

  cubeWrap.style.transitionDuration="0s";
  cube.style.transitionDuration="0s";
  cubeContainer.style.transitionDuration="0s";

  cubeWrap.style.transform="initial";
  cubeContainer.style.transform="initial";
  cube.style.transform="initial"; 
}

function clicked( event ) {
  const element = event.target;

  if( element.classList == `x-rotate` ) {
    if(rotplane!=1){
        clearTransform();
        rotplane=1;
        roty=0;
    }

    roty+=45;
    cubeContainer.style.transform = `rotateY( ${roty}deg )`;
    cubeContainer.style.transitionDuration="1s";

  }else if( element.classList == `y-rotate` ) {
    if(rotplane!=2){
        clearTransform();
        rotplane=2;
        rotx=0;
    }

    rotx-=45;
    cubeWrap.style.transform = `rotateX( ${rotx}deg )`;
    cubeWrap.style.transitionDuration="1s";

  }else if( element.classList == `z-rotate` ) {    
       if(rotplane!=3){
        clearTransform();
        rotplane=3;
        rotz=0;
       }

    rotz+=45
    cube.style.transform = `rotateZ( ${rotz}deg )`;
    cube.style.transitionDuration="1s";

  }
}

aside.addEventListener( `click`, clicked );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. For example if I click the top control and then the middle one the cube transforms in more than just one axis after the second click ( middle button ). I agree with you on the finding a different approach though. MY code isn't sustainable because it keeps adding to the `transform` property. Can't think of any other way to do this at the moment unless I could somehow convert `matrix3D` values to regular `transform` values. Then that might help me with my question as well.

Comment: You'll have to set your transition-duration to 0 for the reset, then back to whatever value you need for the actual transform.  As I said, it's a quick hack :)

Comment: Didn't realize you edited this answer again before I answered my own question. This approach is better and almost works 100% of the time but when switching between some controls quickly it seems to behave erratically.

Comment: If the angle is not mod 90, increment or decrement by 45 to show a flat face, then the transform will be smooth and not snap quickly like it does in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to make this work by always wrapping the cube in a parent element when a control is clicked and applying transforms to that parent. As mentioned by @Creon Noir this is a pretty terrible approach as it's continually creating parent elements and applying transforms to these elements. The DOM could have hundreds or thousands of elements should a user click that many times.

This is however the only working solution I could find to my original question.

```js
const 
  doc = document,
  qS = `querySelector`,
  scene = doc[ qS ]( `.scene` ),
  aside = doc[ qS ]( `aside` );

function clicked( event ) {
  const element = event.target;

  if( element.classList == `x-rotate` ) {
    scene.innerHTML = `<section>${ scene.innerHTML }</section>`;
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        scene.children[ 0 ].style.transform += `rotateY( 45deg )`;
      }, 
      1
    )
  }
  if( element.classList == `y-rotate` ) {
    scene.innerHTML = `<section>${ scene.innerHTML }</section>`;
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        scene.children[ 0 ].style.transform += `rotateX( -45deg )`;
      }, 
      1
    )
  }
  if( element.classList == `z-rotate` ) {
    scene.innerHTML = `<section>${ scene.innerHTML }</section>`;
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        scene.children[ 0 ].style.transform += `rotateZ( 45deg )`;
      }, 
      1
    )
  }
}

aside.addEventListener( `click`, clicked );
```

```css
body, section, aside, div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
:root {
  --length: 10rem; --dim: rgba( 0,0,0,0.125 );
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
body {
  perspective: 15rem;
  font-family: Arial;
}
section {
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
.scene {
  transform: translateZ( -7.5rem );
}
.cube-container, .cube-container div {
  width: var( --length );
  height: var( --length );
  position: absolute;
}
.cube > div > div {
  transform: translateZ( 5rem );
}
.cube > div > div:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translateZ( 5rem );
}
.cube > div > div > div {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 1rem inset;
  background-color: var( --dim );
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: transform, box-shadow, background-color;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-out;
}
.cube > div > div > div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 1rem #099 inset;
  background-color: rgba( 0,220,220,0.5 );
}
.cube > div > div > div:active {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 2rem #033 inset;
}
.cube .left-right {
  transform: rotateY( 90deg );
}
.cube .top-bottom {
  transform: rotateX( 90deg );
}
.cube .transform {
  transform: translateZ( 5rem ) scale( 0.75 );
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 3rem inset;
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.75 );
}
.cube .transform:hover {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 4rem #099 inset;
}
aside {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform: scale( 0.65 );
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0rem;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  max-width: 10rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: rgba( 220,220,220,0.5 );
  backdrop-filter: blur( 1rem );
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 1rem );
}
aside svg {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  transform: scale( 0.65 );
  cursor: pointer;
}
aside svg:hover, aside svg:active {
  fill: #0dd;
}
aside svg:active {
  filter: brightness( 75% );
}
aside svg.y-rotate {
  transform: scale( 0.65 ) rotateZ( 90deg ) scaleY( -1 );
}
```

```html
<!-- \\\ \\\ \\\ SCENE /// /// /// -->
<section class='scene'>
  <!-- \ \ \ CUBE CONTAINER / / / -->
  <div class='cube-container'>
    <!-- \ \ \ CUBE WRAP / / / -->
    <div class='cube-wrap'>
      <!-- \ \ \ CUBE / / / -->
      <div class='cube'>
        <!-- \ front-back / -->
        <div class='front-back'>
          <!-- \ front-wrap / -->
          <div class='front-wrap'>
            <!-- \ front-face / -->
            <div class='front face'>
            </div>
            <!-- / front-face \ -->
          </div>
          <!-- / front-wrap \ -->
          <!-- \ back-wrap / -->
          <div class='back-wrap'>
            <!-- \ back-face / -->
            <div class='back face'>
            </div>
            <!-- / back-face \ -->
          </div>   
          <!-- / back-wrap \ -->
        </div>
        <!-- / front-back \ -->
        <!-- \ left-right / -->
        <div class='left-right'>
          <!-- \ left-wrap / -->
          <div class='left-wrap'>
            <!-- \ left-face / -->
            <div class='left face'>
            </div>
            <!-- / left-face \ -->
          </div>
          <!-- / left-wrap \ -->
          <!-- \ right-wrap / -->
          <div class='right-wrap'>
            <!-- \ right-face / -->
            <div class='right face'>
            </div>
            <!-- / right-face \ -->
          </div>        
          <!-- / right-wrap \ -->
        </div>   
        <!-- / left-right \ -->
        <!-- \ top-bottom / -->
        <div class='top-bottom'>
          <!-- \ top-wrap / -->
          <div class='top-wrap'>
            <!-- \ top-wrap / -->
            <div class='top face'>
            </div>
            <!-- / top-wrap \ -->
          </div>
          <!-- / top-wrap \ -->
          <!-- \ bottom-wrap / -->
          <div class='bottom-wrap'>
            <!-- \ bottom-face / -->
            <div class='bottom face'>
            </div>
            <!-- / bottom-face \ -->
          </div>         
          <!-- / bottom-wrap \ -->
        </div> 
        <!-- / top-bottom \ -->
      </div>
      <!-- / / / CUBE \ \ \ -->
    </div>
    <!-- / / / CUBE WRAP \ \ \ -->
  </div>
  <!-- / / / CUBE CONTAINER \ \ \ -->
</section>
<!-- /// /// /// SCENE \\\ \\\ \\\ -->
<!-- \\\ \\\ \\\ ASIDE /// /// /// -->
<aside>
  <!-- \\\ \\\ \\\ X-ROTATE /// /// /// -->
  <svg class='x-rotate'>
    <path 
      class='x-rotate'
      d=
        '
          M 42,75
          C 50,70,58,63,65,59
          C 58,53,50,48,42,43
          V 53
          C -25,44,56,28,82,41
          C 91,46,78,50,72,51
          V 62
          C 114,51,100,28,59,26
          C 18,24,-14,41,10,56
          C 21,62,30,62,42,64
          Z
        '
    />
  </svg>
  <!-- /// /// /// X-ROTATE \\\ \\\ \\\ -->
  <!-- \\\ \\\ \\\ Y-ROTATE /// /// /// -->
  <svg class='y-rotate'>
    <path 
      class='y-rotate'
      d=
        '
          M 42,75
          C 50,70,58,63,65,59
          C 58,53,50,48,42,43
          V 53
          C -25,44,56,28,82,41
          C 91,46,78,50,72,51
          V 62
          C 114,51,100,28,59,26
          C 18,24,-14,41,10,56
          C 21,62,30,62,42,64
          Z
        '
    />
  </svg>
  <!-- /// /// /// Y-ROTATE \\\ \\\ \\\ -->
  <!-- \\\ \\\ \\\ Z-ROTATE /// /// /// -->
  <svg class='z-rotate'>
    <path 
      class='z-rotate'
      d=
        '
          M 94,65
          L 83,61
          C 79,70,73,77,63,80
          C 44,87,23,77,17,59
          C 7,24,48,0,76,26
          L 64,32 L 96,50 L 97,15 L 86,20
          C 62,-4,32,4,17,18
          C -8,44,7,77,27,87
          C 52,100,85,90,94,65
          Z
        '
    />
  </svg>
  <!-- /// /// /// Z-ROTATE \\\ \\\ \\\ -->
</aside>
<!-- /// /// /// ASIDE \\\ \\\ \\\ -->
```